# wp-cli cron not executing

Tags: cron

wp 6 civi 5.52

cron command is [image]

errors seem to be only warnings but civi reports cron not running:

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/utils.php on line 1194
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Loggers/Regular.php on line 43
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Loggers/Base.php on line 66
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Loggers/Regular.php on line 52
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Loggers/Base.php on line 66
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Would be worth checking if there is a newer version of wp-cli than the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

With assistance from webhost
This command worked

[image]